# Angular 2: loading individual data for ngFor items on demand

Tags: angular, ngfor, subscribe

I have an app which loads items from mongodb and puts them in a list using ngFor. Now each item also has a button to load more data about this item, **but when I load data for one item, the same data is automatically added to all other items.**

I guess, I could do some ngIf solution, but is there a more elegant way to do this.

This is in my data service file to load data from mongo:

```
getProjectData(companyID, projectID): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`/api/get_test_project/${companyID}/${projectID}`).map(result => this.result = result.json());
}
```

This is in my component file to get the data (extra question here, am I doing this correctly, should I use some other method to get the data, since I load it only once?)

```
loadProject(companyID, projectID) {
    this.dataSubscription = this.dataService.getProjectData(companyID, projectID).subscribe(res => this.projectData = res);
}
```

This is my for loop:

```
<div  *ngFor="let projects of company.projects;">
    {{projects.project.name}}
    <div  click)="loadProject(company.id, projects.project.id)">
        LOAD MORE DATA
    </div>
    <div>
        MORE DATA:
        {{this.projectData | json}}
    </div>
</div>
```

It all works, but as I said, when I press the LOAD MORE DATA button, all items get the same data about the clicked item.

EDIT: Instead of loading a new array of items, should I try and merge the new array of items with the existing one (the one that creates the initial ngFor loop) ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you update `this.projectData` variable, and use the same variable for every item inside your `*ngFor` loop. One of the proper ways will be to merge the `company.projects` array with new received `getProjectData` response. Add this data to that array element, for which you get it from server, and interpolate it like this instead of using one variable for all iterated items:

```
{{projects.projectData | json}}
```

But be ready, that for some items there will not be a value.

**P.S:** I described the main idea, you should think about the structure of your array and `*ngFor` loop.